# How to get the network uri of a file being downloaded from the Download Manager in Android

Tags: java, android

I am writing an application wherein I want to detect if a download has started and retrieve the URI of the file being downloaded and then cancel the download from the Download Manager. I am doing this so that I can send this URI somewhere else.

The trouble is that I can detect when a download begins by querying the Download Manager, but is there a method or a constant variable in Download Manager from which I can also get the URL of the file being downloaded

Comment: I sure hope what you are trying to do is impossible, as it would be a serious security breach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok its weird answering your own question, but I finally figured out how to do this. There is a DownloadManager class in android.app, which stores a list of all http downloads initiated and their statuses. These can be filtered out based on whether the download is 'RUNNING', 'PENDING', 'PAUSED' and so on.

This list can be read into a cursor and one of the columns of the result is 'COLUMN_URI', which is the url from where the file is being downloaded. A sample code where I have used it is as given below:

```
public void readDownloadManager() {
                DownloadManager.Query query = null;
                DownloadManager downloadManager = null;
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                    //Just for testing I initiated my own download from this url. When an http
                    // reuest for this url is made, since download is taking place, it gets saved in
                    // the download manager.
                    Request request = new Request(Uri.parse("http://ocw.mit.edu/courses" +
                            "/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-100-aerodynamics-fall-2005" +
                            "/lecture-notes/16100lectre1_kvm.pdf"));
                    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                    query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING);
                    c = downloadManager.query(query);

                    if(true){
                        int statusColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        int urlColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI);
                        long downloadProcessIdColumnNo = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID);
                        Log.d("Column Count", ((Integer)c.getCount()).toString());
                        if(c.getCount() > 0){
                            String url="";
                            c.moveToLast();
                            if(c.isLast()){
                                url = c.getString(urlColumnIndex);
                                downloadManager.remove(downloadProcessIdColumnNo);
                                Log.d("Count after remove", ((Integer)c.getCount()).toString());
                            }
                            Log.d("After", "Stopped Working");

                            //Here I am sending the url to another activity, where I can work with it.
                            Intent intent = new Intent(EasyUploadMainMenu.this, EasyUploadActivity.class);
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("url", url);
                            intent.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Log.d("url:", url);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Fortunately, this technique seems to only work for downloads from your own process.